# javax.persistence.Persistence - ClassNotFoundException in dynamic web project

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using a JPA project as a jar in a dynamic webproject.

At a certain moment in my project I get a ***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence*** error.

[image]

```
operation = RepositoryFactory.getRepositoryFactory()
        .getUserRepository().add(feedbackverantwoordelijke);
```

> 

```
public boolean add(User user) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = HibernateRepositoryFactory
            .getEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    User tempUser = null;
    try {
        // checking if the entity is already in the repository
        if (user.getId() != null) {
            tempUser = em.find(User.class, user.getId());
            //delete
            System.out.println(user.getId());
            //
        }
        // if no persist the entity
        if (tempUser == null) {
            em.persist(user);
        } else {
            // if so, get the differences and persist them
            tempUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            tempUser.setUserName(user.getUserName());
            tempUser = em.merge(user);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logging.error("Deze melding trad op bij het toevoegen van een user"
                + " :" + e);
    }
    tx.commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
    return true;
}
```

note : Feedbackverantwoordelijke extends User

This works perfect from within my JPA project.  But when I call this from the JPA jar in my dynamic webproject I get the error.

It seems I'm missing a jar('s) when running this in my dynamic webproject.  Normally all jars are in my JPA project and I can do all CRUD operation in my JPA project??

Must I load some jar's in my Dynamic Web project??  And if so, must I place them in my WEB-INF/lib folder??

I'm also using the joda-time jar in my JPA project and web mail jar.  Must I place those jar's also in my dynamic webproject.

Thx for the reply's

Comment: Can you provide any code to go with this?

Comment: Thx for the downvote.  I can provide code but the use of it is no use.  I get the error at the moment when I try to use the repositoryfunction to check something in the db.  Like stated this works fine from within the JPA project.  But from within my dynamic webproject with the JPA project as a jar I can't.  So as stated I think I'm missing a jar, but normally all jar's are in my JPA project?!

Comment: You must provide a JPA implementation at runtime, how to do it differs between application servers. Btw: what is the difference between "??" and "?"?

Comment: @esej this dynamic webproject runs on a Apache Tomcat server

Comment: I don't know anything about using tomcat derivitvies as Java (EE) containers, but isn't Tomcat without JPA and TomEE with JPA (and some other goodies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.  I needed to add the hibernate jars and also the other external jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder of my dynamic webproject.  Now I can persist to the db.